# Javascript not working in firefox: undefined variables?

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    var secs = ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
    var minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(secs % 60);
    var tsecs = ytplayer.getDuration();
    var tminutes = Math.floor(tsecs / 60);
    var tseconds = Math.floor(tsecs % 60);
    var time = minutes + ":" + seconds + " / " + tminutes + ":" + tseconds;
    document.getElementById('currenttime').innerHTML = time;
}, 1000);
```

This code does not work in firefox but it does in chrome and IE.

I checked with firebug and it says that the variables secs, minutes, seconds, tsecs, tminutes, tseconds and time are not defined.

I dont know how to fix this because I did use var to define them. Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you do : `new Date()` ?

Comment: i suppose `ytplayer` is a video player of some sort.

Comment: YouTube Player i believe

Comment: check whether enable JavaScript is checked in browser's settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have an element with the id `ytplayer` and are assuming that `window.ytplayer` will be created automatically.

Don't make that assumption. Use `document.getElementById` (and make sure you have a Doctype that triggers Standards mode).

Comment: Actually I have document.getElementById earlier in the code so I thought that It would already be defined. 
`var ytplayer = document.getElementById(&quot;ytplayer&quot;);`
Putting that in the function makes it work but why do I have to declare it in every function?

Comment: Presumably because the [scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) you put it is wasn't wide enough.

Comment: Ok ill look up about scope. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    var secs = ytplayer.getCurrentTime(),
    minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60),
    seconds = Math.floor(secs % 60),
    tsecs = ytplayer.getDuration(),
    tminutes = Math.floor(tsecs / 60),
    tseconds = Math.floor(tsecs % 60),
    time = minutes + ":" + seconds + " / " + tminutes + ":" + tseconds;
    document.getElementById('currenttime').innerHTML = time;
},1000);
```

and make sure ytplayer is already there.